Azure with Node.js : missing and unauthorized resources
I am new to deployment stuff, and just started using azure.
I have a project in which I am asked to deploy an app, that will later have to interact with other aspects of Azure. So I decided to use an app I had used a year before, that runs perfectly well locally.
What it does is pretty simple, it would find index.html in /views, and display it on base route '/'. When I entered '/earthquakes' it would fetch a MongoDB database and collection for data and list said data, making each row clickable to access a '/earthquakes:id' route that would display more detailed data on the selected row.
As I was trying many fixes, I decided to get rid of the database part for now and only focus on having the Nodejs app working, which still doesn't. 
Whenever I try to access the app thanks to its link after deploying through Azure, I inevitably have the following errors :
You do not have permission to view this directory or page. - When on '/'
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. - When on '/test' or any other route.
Below the structure of my folder : 
baseUrl.js 
index.js 
package.json
package-lock.js
/views
  earthquakes.pug
  earthquakes_details.pug
  index.html
Below the code I'm using in index.js :
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const path = require('path');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

let client;

/*async function connectDB() {
  try {
    const url = process.env.DB_URI; // Utilisation de la variable d'environnement DB_URI
    client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    console.log('Connexion à la base de données réussie');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Impossible de se connecter à la base de données :', err);
  }
}


app.use(['/earthquakes', '/earthquakes/:id'], async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!client) {
    await connectDB();
  }
  next();
});

app.get('/earthquakes', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const db = client.db('earthquake2023').limit(3);
    console.log('user sur /earthquakes');

    const results = await db.collection('earthquakes').find().toArray();
    res.render('earthquakes', { earthquakes: results });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send('Une erreur est survenue.');
  }
});

app.get('/earthquakes/:id', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const db = client.db('earthquake2023');
    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log('user sur /earthquakes/' + id);

    const result = await db.collection('earthquakes').findOne({ id: id });
    console.log('Données de l\'earthquake transmises à la vue :', result);
    res.render('earthquake_details', { earthquake: result });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send('Une erreur est survenue.');
  }
});*/

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Ceci est un test');
});
  
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('user sur /');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

const baseUrl = require('./baseUrl');

app.listen(3001, function() {
  console.log('Le serveur est démarré sur le port 3001');
});

baseUrl.js containes the URL I get from azure after deploying.
I tried checking if wwwroot contained my project's file and if they were accessible (read with ls -l on ssh) and they were.
I tried commenting any database interactions to test Node only, and still, doesn't help.
If anyone has an idea of why, it's be huge help.
Thanks in advance !

Are you deploying your web app to Azure as a Windows or Linux web app?

How are you configuring the port number in your Node.js web app?

I Observed you are Hardcoded Port number in your index.js , Change port assignment like this const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;.

Hello ! I'm deploying on Windows. As for the port, it's probably the default one 3000 or the one I used in index.js 3001, it is not showned when accessing through Azure.
I forgot to precise that I used Azure Portal to do most of the config. I'm asking here before doing an overhaul using Visual Studio Code and plug-ins only as a last chance.

After deploying to azure the port is changed, process.env.PORT this line is helped to change the port automatically from environments.

okay I'll do that, is there anything else that seems wrong before I eventually deploy again ?
Thank you so much for the help too !

If possible, Provide your Github repo here. I will try from my End.

https://github.com/MohciniH/eqfinder-azure

Have you tried the solution which I have shared?

I tried your code, deployed it to the Azure web app(Windows), and it was successfully deployed.
I added the following lines to your package.json:
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }

package.json:
{
  "name": "eqfinder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^7.0.6",
    "mongodb": "^5.2.0",
    "pug": "^3.0.2"
  }
}

I added this line: const port = process.env.PORT || 3001; and I edited this line: app.listen(port, function() {});.
I removed this line of code: //const baseUrl = require('./baseUrl');.
Below is the complete index.js file.
index.js:
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dotenv = require('dotenv'); 
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
let client;
/*async function connectDB() {
  try {
    const url = process.env.DB_URI; // Utilisation de la variable d'environnement DB_URI
    client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    console.log('Connexion à la base de données réussie');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Impossible de se connecter à la base de données :', err);
  }
}
app.use(['/earthquakes', '/earthquakes/:id'], async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!client) {
    await connectDB();
  }
  next();
});
app.get('/earthquakes', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const db = client.db('earthquake2023').limit(3);
    console.log('user sur /earthquakes');
    const results = await db.collection('earthquakes').find().toArray();
    res.render('earthquakes', { earthquakes: results });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send('Une erreur est survenue.');
  }
});

app.get('/earthquakes/:id', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const db = client.db('earthquake2023');
    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log('user sur /earthquakes/' + id);
    const result = await db.collection('earthquakes').findOne({ id: id });
    console.log('Données de l\'earthquake transmises à la vue :', result);
    res.render('earthquake_details', { earthquake: result });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send('Une erreur est survenue.');
  }
});*/
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Ceci est un test');
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('user sur /');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});
//const baseUrl = require('./baseUrl');
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Le serveur est démarré sur le port 3001');
});

After deploying to the Azure web app, I can see the output in the browser.
Azure Web App output:



@Hicham Mohcini Have you Tried the solution which I have Provided?
